# TypeError: (...).map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-tsx

I'm new to both javascript and react so there may be many things wrong here.

I have an interface `LiquidityPosition` that I'm trying to display as components through my `LiquidityList` component. I pass `LiquidityList` an array of type `LiquidityPosition[]`.

Here is my app.tsx:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import LiquidityList from './components/LiquidityList';
import { LiquidityPosition } from './components/Liquidity'

function App() {
  let positions = [
    {
      time: new Date(2018, 11, 24, 10, 33, 30, 0),
      sizeA: 2,
      sizeB: 1
    }
  ]
  return (
    <>
      <LiquidityList {...positions}/>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

LiquidityList.tsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import { LiquidityPosition } from './Liquidity';
import Liquidity from './Liquidity';

export default function LiquidityList(posList: LiquidityPosition[]) {
  return (
    <>
      {
        posList.map(pos => <Liquidity {...pos}/>)
      }
    </>
  )
}
```

For some reason here, posList is not an array, since it doesn't have a `.map` method? The error message:

```
TypeError: posList.map is not a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument provided to a component is an object, each of whose properties corresponds to a prop passed down by the parent. For example, passing down

```
foo={5}
```

results in the component's argument being equivalent to

```
{
  foo: 5
}
```

The component argument shouldn't be an array - it should be an object containing the one `positions` prop. Take the individual prop out of the object to get to the array.

In the parent:

```
<LiquidityList {...{positions}}/>
```

or

```
<LiquidityList positions={positions} />
```

In the child, if you want to pass down `pos` as the prop:

```
export default function LiquidityList({ positions }: { positions: LiquidityPosition[] }) {
  return positions.map(pos => <Liquidity pos={pos}/>);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was basically it except I had to add `<>` and `</>` around the return value in the child.